# Adding auth to existing project with Laravel Alpine and Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have an existing laravel project with AlpineJS. I wanted to integrate authentication but not able to find a proper solution having in mind **I DONT USE VUE**. I have done this with Vue but just wanted to know if there's an updated guide for Laravel with **Alpine JS**. I tried to look into documentation but wasnt able to find something related.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
```

Do I still need to do this? Any suggestions for best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Alpine](https://alpinejs.dev/) is just a lightweight framework for DOM manipulation, it's not going to provide any authentication functionality alone so you will need to add something to your project.

If you're wanting to add authentication to your application, you'll want to consider something like Laravel [Fortify](https://github.com/laravel/fortify) which is a headless front end agnostic authentication solution. There are starter kits such as [Breeze](https://github.com/laravel/breeze) or [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/introduction.html), however, adding either of these boilerplate start kits to existing projects can have issues. Some people recommend starting a new project, installing one of them and them porting your existing functionality across (this will obviously depend on the scale of your project).

Comment: Yes I added *Breeze* but it literally changed a lot.